# How to restore my last amended commit from `git reset --hard`?

Tags: git, git-reset

Fortunately, I executed `amend previous commit` before accidently executed

`git reset origin/myBranch --hard`.

How can I restore my last amended commit?

Comment: Use `git reflog` (or other means) to find the commit and then reset the branch to the specific commit. In Windows, I highly recommend GitExtensions for browsing history via UI.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-reset%5D+undo+hard+reset